# What is the proper way to type and use a state variable in React (with typescript) when it can be of several types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a react select component with the following state :

```
 const [value, setValue] = useState<ValueType>()
```

where `isMulti` is a boolean and the type `ValueType` is defined like this :

```
type Option = {label: string, value: string} 
type ValueType = Option | Option[]
```

The problem I face is that I don't know which type of data the state value will receive. It could be either an object of type Option ({label: string, value: string}), an array of Options, as defined in the ValueType type.

I then have this onChange handler :

```
const onChange = (opt: ValueType) => {
      setValue(!isMulti ? opt.value : opt.map((opt: { value: string }) => opt.value));
    }
```

There, opt is either an object or an array of objects based on boolean `isMulti` , therefore the condition `!isMulti ? opt.value : opt.map((opt: { value: string }) => opt.value)` is throwing 2 errors :

- `opt.value` => property 'value' doesn't exist on type 'ValueType'
  which is normal because in this case opt is on object of type Option
- `opt.map()` => property 'map' doesn't exist on type 'ValueType'

Of course, deleting the ternary operator solves it. Unfortunately I can't modify the select component to return only an object, or only an array of objects, since we need both and it is already in use throughout the project.

My question is :

How can I define the `opt` parameter in `onChange()` function so that the condition in `setValue()` based on the `isMulti` boolean doesn't throw those errors ?
Is there any 'good practice' related to that use case ?

If anyone can provide any help on that matter, it will be very much appreciated.

Comment: `setValue(!Array.isArray(opt) ? opt.value : opt.map((opt: { value: string }) => opt.value));`

Comment: @vr. thanks for your help, but unfortunately I still get the error `opt.value => property 'value' doesn't exist on type 'ValueType'`

Comment: Is there a strong reason to not just have it be `Option[]` and force one to always send an array, even if one element?

Comment: @crashmstr that would indeed be the proper way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could force typescript to detect a specific type for your opt.

```
setValue(!isMulti ? (opt as Option).value : (opt as Option[]).map((opt: { value: string }) => opt.value));
```

But if you want to avoid all that, I would only set the Option[] type and set an array of one element when only one Option.

If I got the problem right, this might fix your issue :-)

Comment: Thanks @LoveriusB. I actually ended up with replacing `!isMulti` with `!Array.isArray(opt)` as @vr suggested and your solution works perfectly until we dive into the refactoring of the whole component

Comment: Glad I could be of any help! Cheers :-)